# In PHP, enable the bracket syntax for accessing by index in a custom class

Tags: php

Is there a way to enable this syntax for classes you write:

```
$object= new my_array_like_class;
// some code that modifies the contents goes here
// now to access a value by index, I want to enable this array like syntax:
$value= $object[$index];
```

I know this can be used for arrays, but I am wondering if there is any way to do this with custom types.

Comment: You mean `$object->$index`?

Comment: I wish I could clarify the question, but it is not letting me edit it for some reason... I usually realize a way to clarify my questions right after I ask them...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

Comment: I am referring to a custom syntax that would map $object[$index] to a specific method. Even there is no clean way to do this, any hacks that allow this syntax would still be useful to know about, even if their use is discouraged.

Comment: @zerkms If you make that into a full answer, I will probably accept it.

Comment: It's really a link-only answer. Too bored to answer in details on something like that :-)

Comment: @zerkms Well thanks, that is what I was looking for. It's easy points for someone who wants to write a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @zerkms pointed out, this is possible with any class that implements the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface.

The easiest way of all would be to use the [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) class, which is native to PHP and already implements the `ArrayAccess` interface, which can be used on its own:

```
$object = new ArrayObject;
...
$value= $object[$index];
```

Or extended:

```
class MyArrayLikeClass extends ArrayObject {
    ...
}

$object = new MyArrayLikeClass;
...
$value= $object[$index];
```

If you decide not to use `ArrayObject` for whatever reason and implement `ArrayAccess` on your own, you may also be interested in [`IteratorAggregate`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php), which is a convenient way to make your object traversable (i.e. usable by `foreach`).